# Iterar tuplas y asignar variables por cada iteración

Tags: python

Amigos tengo un pequeño problema, es el siguiente tengo una base de datos y realizó una consulta a la base de datos y está me devuelve una tupla principal y en su interior tiene otras tuplas segundarias, que almacenan como mínimo 5 valores en cada tupla segundaria, lo que necesito es poder iterar con un for esa tupla y en cada iteración me entrega una nueva tupla entonces necesito almacenar esa nueva tupla en una variable, no sé cómo asignar variables a cada iteración, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Por favor muéstranos lo que has intentado y el ejemplo de data. Lee el guia aqui https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `list()` crea una lista a partir de un iterable. Todo lo que necesitas es aplicar la función sobre la tupla leida y pasar el resultado a `DataFrame`.

```
leido = ((1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12))
df = pd.DataFrame(list(leido), columns=list("ABCD"))
print(df)
```

resulta en:

```
   A   B   C   D
0  1   2   3   4
1  5   6   7   8
2  9  10  11  12
```